# Is union types with typescript consisting of a generic type and a function broken?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building a list manager which constraints to unique values, with all sorts of utility functions. However wrapping the array find and findIndex method seems to break and looking in the output, typescript is misinterpreting.

This is part of an angular 7 library I am building, search attempts on the web have not proved helpful as none outlay my very specific finding.

```
export abstract class ListManagerAbstract<T> {

    find(findStrategy?: T | ((item: T, index: number, obj: T[]) => boolean)) {
        if (typeof findStrategy === 'function') {
            return this.list.find(findStrategy);
        }

        return this.list.find((value: T) => value === findStrategy);
    }
}
```

I expect this to work obviously.

The below error states Type ***'T & Function' is not assignable to type***, so it looks like he thinks the type is both the generic T as a Function (since he flags both). Am I misinterpreting the output? Is this broken? What is going on here?

```
Type 'T & Function' is not assignable to type '(value: T, index: number, obj: T[]) => boolean'.
Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature '(value: T, index: number, obj: T[]): boolean'.
```

Comment: Note that `&` is an *intersection* type, not a *union* type; see http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: Yes but | is a union type, and that is what Im using. I dont understand where that _& Function_ is coming from

Answer (score 0):

For those that get thrown off by this as well the answer is relatively simple:

T doesnt exclude being a function, so it could potentially be a function hence the error is thrown :)